# Obtaining two strings from a instruction

Tags: c, string, input

I'm doing a work that imply the use of instructions to do certain operations in files, that will be read from an archive, or will be given by input.

Precisely my question involves the operations with **instruction given by input**.

Let's suppose I give to my program the following **instructions**:

```
select 7
insert "foo foo"
delete 8
```

In the code shown below, I will get the **complete instruction** (like the ones shown above) in **one string**:

```
char input[256];
int i;

printf("Insert an instruction: ");
fgets(input, 256, stdin);

/* Newline removal */
for(i = strlen(input)-1; i && input[i] < ' '; i--)
input[i] = 0;
```

Now, as you can see, the instructions **divide in two parts**, **first is the action** to be done. Taking the example, the actions are these:

```
select
insert
delete
```

And then is the **number or the string that will accompany that instruction**. In the example given:

```
7
"foo foo"
8
```

So, basically, I have the complete instruction, but I want that instruction in **two separate strings**, so I can work better with them.

How can I do it? Do I need to input in another way, or split the string? Or I need more than two strings for this situation?

Comment: Do you want to do this yourself with your own loop, or do you want to know how you should do it "real" application, using standard library functions (or even regexp library or a tokenizer like *flex*)?

Comment: I don't see too much necessary the second option (for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to strdup() your input, then you can cut into two separate strings. If you aren't worried about modifying the input, then you don't have to strdup it, but in my opinion it's good practice.

```
#include    <string.h>

int main() 
{
char *p ;
char *cmd ;
char *arg ;

char input[256] ;

strcpy(input,"command  argument") ;

char *t = strdup(input) ;  /* if you cannot modify the input */

p = cmd = t ;
while (*p != ' ' && *p != 0 && *p != '\n') p++ ;
*p++ = 0 ;
while (*p == ' ') p++ ;
arg = p ;

return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Testing the code (with help of located `printf()`s) I am looking that the action isn't stored. The number/string (even with blank spaces) is totally stored.

Comment: apologies. i will fix it

Comment: sorry that was a little bit sloppy

Comment: I located where is the command string. To handle it, I created a char variable for copying it. Also I created a char variable for the argument. I don't think it's really necessary the second auxiliar variable, but it helps to clarify where is located the string of the argument.